# Why are resent messages discarded in QuickFIX?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I have a QuickFIX/J application running as acceptor. ResetOnLogon is N in the configuration.

When the initiator is logged on, since the seq nums are different the initiator app sends the messages and I see those messages in the FIX log file. The first one of those message is passed to the application layer but the others are not, all are discarded.

What can be the reason that the messages are received but not passed to the application level?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is that the messages contain the PossDupFlag <43> with a 'Y' value, and a MsgSeqNum <34> that is infact recognized as a dupe by the engine. In that case you won't receive these as application level messages.